# Express4 handlebars compile template to variable

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm currently rendering a handlebars templates to display pages on my node server. I've set the view engine to handlebars

```
res.render('product', vars);
```

However, I would like to run the compiled HTML template through [juice2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/juice2) so that the styles are inlined. Because the page is rendered on request, I cannot format the HTML before being sent to the client.

Is there any way of rendering the template server side (to a variable preferably, formatting the content in juice2 and then outputting them)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
res.render('product', vars, function(err, html) {
    juice.juiceContent(html, options, function(err, finalHTML) {
        res.send(finalHTML); 
    })
});
// options.url = base domain like http://example.com
```

References:

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/juice2#juicejuicecontenthtml-options-callback
2. http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res

Comment: Example - <a href="/contact.php">Contact</a> . You could expect it should turn to <a href="http:// example.com/contact.php">Contact</a>..  hence options.url = "http:// example.com"